# array subscript is not an integer [counting sort]

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

i need to write a counting sort algorithm which is sorting strings by the first letter, but i got "error: array subscript is not an integer" in Count function. there is probably need to use ASCII, but i don't know how. any ideas?

```
aaa.c: In function ‘Count’:
aaa.c:20:23: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
           C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);
                       ^
aaa.c:20:33: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
           C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);
                                 ^
aaa.c:20:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);
               ^
aaa.c:22:25: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                B[(int)C[(int)A[j]]]=A[j];
                         ^
aaa.c:22:18: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                B[(int)C[(int)A[j]]]=A[j];
                  ^
aaa.c:23:18: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                C[(int)A[j]]=C[(int)A[j]]-1;
                  ^
aaa.c:23:31: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                C[(int)A[j]]=C[(int)A[j]]-1;



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MaxStringLength 30
#define MaxStringNumber 5
#define NumberOfLetters 26

char **A;
char **B;
char **C;

void Count(char **A, char **B, int quantity){
        int i,j;

        for (i=1;i<=NumberOfLetters;i++) C[i]=0;
        for (j=1;j<=quantity;j++)
             C[A[j][1]-96] +=1;
        for (i=2;i<=NumberOfLetters;i++)
          C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);     
        for (j=MaxStringNumber;j>0;j--){
               B[(int)C[(int)A[j]]]=A[j]; 
               C[(int)A[j]]=C[(int)A[j]]-1;

        }
}

void printing(char **array, int quantity){
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=quantity;i++)
                printf("%s \n", array[i]);
}

void reading(char **array, int quantity){
        char word[MaxStringLength];
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=quantity; i++){
                scanf("%s",word);
                array[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*MaxStringLength);
                strcpy(array[i],word);
        }
}

int main(){
        A=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber+1)*sizeof(char*));
        B=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber+1)*sizeof(char*));
        C=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber+1)*sizeof(char*));

        printf("Array A:\n");
        reading(A,MaxStringNumber);
        Count(A,B,MaxStringNumber);
        printf("Sorted:\n");
        printing(B,MaxStringNumber);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sure it is giving the line number where the error is,, But I'll give you a hint - `A[j]` is not an integer. So what would be `C[A[j]]`?

Comment: i have included errors, but still don't get it

Comment: BTW `i=1;i<=quantity` --> `i=0;i<quantity`

Comment: it should be indexed from 1

Comment: Here `A`, `B` and `C` are arrays of strings i.e. `A[j]` would be a string instead of an ASCII character. If you need the first letter of each string then use `A[j][0]`. Also, if you want to use `A[j][0]` as an array subscript then you may have to subtract character `'A'` or character `'a'` from `A[j][0]` depending on whether `A[j][0]` is a capital letter or a small letter respectively.

Comment: @bardamu you have not allocated enough memory to index from `1` to `length`. You would need `A=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber+1)*sizeof(char*));` and so on.

Comment: i have updated the code, but after writing strings there is a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" any hints? @Nishant

Answer (score 0):

```
eng.c:18:18: error: array subscript is not an integer
                 C[A[j]] = C[A[j]]+1;
```

the error message means what it says.

`A is a`char**`

`A[j]` is therefore `char *`

You cant use `char *` as an array index.

Its really hard to know how to correct it because A,B,C are not good variable names. Maybe you mean `(int)(*A[j])` thats the int value of the first char in the string, but it seems unlikely. First step, change the names of A,B,C to something meaningful.

Comment: i have updated the code, but there are still warnings and  a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" after writing all strings, any hints?

Comment: now that the code compiles you need to put the updated code in the question. I would ask a new question since its a totally different problerm

Comment: I hope you did not use (int)(*A[j]` that will compile but is probaly wrong